# Probably slash bug on rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This 3 of all my rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule  ^.*-en-loire-atlantique-([0-9]+)/.*-a-.*-([0-9]+)$  /sortir21/index.php?com=liste-cat-lieux&t=$1&l=$2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^.*-en-loire-atlantique-([0-9]+)$  /sortir21/index.php?com=liste-cat-ville&t=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^.*-a-.*-([0-9]+)$  /sortir21/index.php?com=liste-ville-lieux&l=$1 [L]
```

from urls

```
concerts-en-loire-atlantique-32/sortir-a-nantes-44000
concerts-en-loire-atlantique-32
sortir-a-nantes-44000
```

Like this the first doesn't work and it's the 3 which is executed

When i change "/" by "-" it works
…`ntique-([0-9]+)-.*-a-.*-([0`…
, so it doesn't want slash

i try to escaped `\/`, nothing

i try `AllowEncodedSlashes On`
, nothing

All my rules are called from htaccess files with MAMP on Mac OS X

Comment: WHat URL are you accessing that you are expecting to get rewritten?

Comment: @JonLin i edited my question with what you want to know